# R: read.csv/read.table not recognizing all columns due to UTF-8 encoded chars

Tags: r, csv, encoding, utf-8

While I am cleansing data that contain some UTF-8 encoded characters, I encounter the issue in the title.

Before describing the issue in further detail, Let me first take some time to explain the sample data, which can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9c2olukarxzo7ma/test.csv?dl=0). The sample data is a .csv of dimension 1 by 11. A quick check that avoids using `read.table` or `read.csv` reveals so.

```
> con <- file(description = file.path(somedir, 'test.csv'), open = 'rb', encoding = 'UTF-8')
> rawContent <- readLines(con = con, encoding = 'UTF-8')
> close(con)

# check dimension
> colcounts <- sapply(rawContent, function(x){length(gregexpr(pattern = ',', text = x)[[1]])})
> names(colcounts) <- seq_along(rawContent)
> colcounts
 1
10
```

The data is also posted here for easy and safe access:

```
> dput(rawContent)
"100003516,B,110102,00921,100044,图书、报纸制版印刷,印刷设备生产,印刷器材文化用品销售,2311,1,"
```

Now, the issue is that the presence of these UTF-8 encoded chars somehow makes readers such as `read.table` and `read.csv` malfunction. To be more specific, it does not recognize all the columns.

```
> df1 = read.table(text = rawContent, header = F, sep = ',', quote = '', comment.char = '', encoding = 'UTF-8')
> dim(df1)
[1]  1 9
> print(df1)
    V1 V2     V3  V4     V5                              V6                        V7 V8 V9
1 100003516  B 110102 921 100044 图书、报纸制版印刷,印刷设备生产 印刷器材文化用品销售,2311  1 NA
```

As you can see, the commas `,` in `V6, V7` are recognized as content even though I have turned off `quote`. Using `read.csv` would yield a similar result, so does `read.delim`. Any comments, suggestions or solutions are all very welcome! Thanks!

Appendix 171013

Here is some additional info regarding system setting for your interests:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936;LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936;LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936"

> l10n_info()
$MBCS
[1] TRUE

$`UTF-8`
[1] FALSE

$`Latin-1`
[1] FALSE

$codepage
[1] 936

> Encoding(rawContent)
[1] "UTF-8"
```

Appendix 20171015

In addition to the excellent answers below, I have also stumped upon a solution by chance. I don't quite understand how it works, but in consistence with what @Karsten W has mentioned, it is probably by bypassing whatever churn the R program may have with setting system locales by storing the data externally. Here are the codes:

```
rawCotent <- "100003516,B,110102,00921,100044,图书、报纸制版印刷,印刷设备生产,印刷器材文化用品销售,2311,1,"

con <- file(description = 'text.csv', open = 'wb', encoding = 'UTF-8')
writeLines(text = rawContent, con = con, useBytes = T)
close(con)

df <- read.csv(file = 'text.csv', header = F, encoding = 'UTF-8')
print(df)
         V1 V2     V3  V4     V5                 V6           V7                   V8   V9 V10 V11
1 100003516  B 110102 921 100044 图书、报纸制版印刷 印刷设备生产 印刷器材文化用品销售 2311   1  NA
```

Comment: You put some effort into the question. Thank you. A lot of people don't want to download files from unknown sources to see data. To make your data available for this question, use `dput(<data>)`. If it's a lot of data, you can take a smaller part by using `dput(head(<data>))`.

Comment: @shea thanks for the suggesstion! I have posted the data as you adviced

Comment: I can not replicate this behaviour. Using `read.csv(text=rawContent, header=FALSE)` I get a `data.frame` with 11 columns.

Comment: @KarstenW. wired. Using your code, I get still get a 9-column `data.frame`. Is it possible that some system configurations cause the difference?

Comment: Could you run `sys.getlocale()` and `l10n_info()` in your console and add the output to the question?

Comment: Also, what is the result of `Encoding(rawContent)` in your console?

Comment: @KarstenW. Hi, I have updated the info as you asked. I manually set local to Chinese in my script using `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "chs")` in order to display Chinese characters properly. Looking forward to your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?Sys.getlocale`:

"Attempts to change the character set (by Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", ), if that implies a different character set) during a session may not work and are likely to lead to some confusion."

I think this is the reason why your code does not work. A quick fix would be

```
cset <- Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "C")
rawContent <- "100003516,B,110102,00921,100044,图书、报纸制版印刷,印刷设备生产,印刷器材文化用品销售,2311,1,"
dat <- read.csv(text=rawContent, header=FALSE)
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", cset)
ncol(dat)
[1] 11
```